# Can search for specific title text and only display description xml?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
    <?php
  $xml=simplexml_load_file("example.com") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
  foreach ($xml->children() as $items) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($items);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo $items->title;
    echo $items->description;
 }
?>
```

I am trying to search for a title that is named something. After that is found I want to only display the description that comes after the title. Can this be done with XML?

Comment: please mention the language in which you are looking for a solution. Also, mention your research for this problem

Comment: Im am lookin for an answer in php, like the code in the question. Dont know what you mean with research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can use xpath here (and modify it to your desired output); so try some version of this:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//item/title[contains(text(),"134 Haukelifjell")]/text()') as $items) 
  { 
    echo $items;
    foreach ($items->xpath('./following-sibling::description/text()') as $desc)
    echo $desc;   
     }
```

I get this output:

```
Ev 134 Haukelifjell (Vestland/Vestfold og Telemark) Vær- og føreforhold: Snø- og isdekke. Klokken 18:15 var det -5 grader, laber bris og skyet. Gjelder fra: 09.01.2020 18:17
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: @andve - Glad to hear it worked. Don't forget to accept the answer if we're done.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse an RSS feed, so you can do it like this:

```
function Feed($url) {
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($feed->channel->item as $content) {
        array_push($result, $content);
    }
    return $result;
}

$title = 'Ev 134 Haukelifjell'; // The title you want to search for

foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f ) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false) 
        echo $f->description;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Vær- og føreforhold: Snø- og isdekke. Klokken 23:05 var det -7 grader, svak vind og klart. Gjelder fra: 09.01.2020 23:14
```